# Pip freeze in docker image does not have the same result as the local installation

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a dependency file which contains these libraries:

```
boto3==1.14.14
Django==3.0.8
django-cors-headers==3.4.0
django-filter==2.3.0
django-guardian==2.3.0
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-gis==0.15
djangorestframework-guardian==0.3.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0
Pillow==7.2.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
python-dotenv==0.13.0
uWSGI==2.0.19
```

When I install it in a clean local virtualenv (`python 3.7` and pip upgraded) using `virtualenvwrapper`, the `pip freeze` command returns a list of dependencies which is not the same one if I install the requirements in a `python:3.7-slim` or `python:3.7` docker image (with pip upgraded too). The libraries that diverge in the docker container are:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
msgpack==0.6.2
packaging==20.3
pep517==0.8.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
progress==1.5
pyparsing==2.4.6
pytoml==0.1.21
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
webencodings==0.5.1
```

These libraries seems to be installed when I setup my local environment. If I recreate a fresh new environment and run `pip freeze` I have this exact same list.

How can we explain the differences between those two?

Comment: The second list looks like a list of dependencies that aren't in the first list.  `certifi` for instance is the reference Python set of TLS root certificates; `requests` is a standard HTTP client library that depends on it; and `boto3` probably depends on both of those.

Comment: Yep but if they are sub dependencies, why aren't they installed in the docker container like in my local virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the `virtualenvwrapper` which use `virtualenv` that have a seed mechanism that will install default libraries.